# Connect to windows image fails with cmd

Tags: docker

I have created a docker image from my windows 7 tar backup. Everything is fine and docker images shows the image.
Now, I do not know how to create a container from this image. It seems it does not know the cmd command at all.
I tried the following:

```
# docker run -it 8bf47055c3d3 cmd
exec: "CMD": executable file not found in $PATH
docker: Error response from daemon: Container command not found or does not exist..


s# docker run -it 8bf47055c3d3 "Windows\System32\cmd.exe"
exec: "CMD": executable file not found in $PATH
docker: Error response from daemon: Container command not found or does not exist..
```

Is there any way to connect?

Comment: try : `docker run -it 8bf47055c3d3 "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"`

Comment: exec: "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe": executable file not found in $PATH

Comment: sorry, try again `docker run -it 8bf47055c3d3  sh -c "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"`

Comment: exec: "sh": executable file not found in $PATH

Comment: ah, sorry, with command to create container from image , you use: `docker run -d --name container_name -p port:port image`

Comment: docker run -d --name sam-container -p 80:80 8bf47055c3d3 -it "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"
1838aed90048257f62c40dfb5737ce44739c74bde17d02102676cefe0fcc552b
docker: Error response from daemon: Container command not found or does not exist..

Comment: you're creating container from image or connect into running container ? I see you're using : `8bf47055c3d3` this is a container ID

Comment: no it's an image ID: # docker images
REPOSITORY                            TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
devops                                latest              8bf47055c3d3        About an hour ago   30.12 GB
bit3/jsass-build-windows-x64          latest              61382610ffbe        6 days ago          1.226 GB

Comment: I imported the image using: cat file.tgz | docker import - devops:latest

Comment: show me the output of this command : `docker images`

Comment: # docker images
REPOSITORY                            TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
devops                                latest              8bf47055c3d3        About an hour ago   30.12 GB

Answer (score 1):

> I did not create any `Dockerfile`. Just took a `.tgz` backup of the windows `C:\` drive and ran the following command in my Linux to create the image:

```
cat file.tgz | docker import - devops:latest
```

I don't understand what you hope to do with this image.
Docker, used on Windows, is used in a boot2docker (tinycore) VM, where it can run container based on Linux images. It would not know how to interpret Windows system calls.

You would need docker for Windows ([Windows 10 with Hyper-V maybe](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2016/04/01/build-2016-container-announcements-hyper-v-containers-and-windows-10-and-powershell-for-docker/), or [Windows Server 2016 TP4+](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-technical-preview), as in "[Running Docker Containers On Windows Server 2016 (Quick Start Guide)](http://ashleypoole.co.uk/2016/docker-containers-windows-server-2016-guide/)") to *hope* running such an image.

Comment: I am using my windows docker image in a Linux environment. but I cannot access it via cmd. isn't it because I shouldav included a dockerfile when creating the image and mentioned the entrypoint?  I did not understand your last paragraph, why should I need docker for windows? I have docker installed on my linux machine and want to create a windows docker image from my .tgz file.

Comment: @user1596226 "why should I need docker for windows?" Because a Linux docker container will run Linux images, not Windows images.